# Dissecting equal sized parts of cylinder

Tags: edit-mode, knife-tool

I am trying to create a cylinder that is dissected into 10 equal sections (filled layers!) to be printed later on. Essentially like in the picture but without those gaps in between, so far I have not managed to dissect the cylinder appropriately, it doesn't split up and I don't know how to separate the cylinder into 10 even parts. That model in the picture is from someone I know as inspiration - I didn't manage to create that!

Can someone help me please, ideally with some screenshots?
Thank you[image]

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as your previous question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267664/creating-a-cube-with-a-set-height-of-layers

Comment: you can use the Array modifier but you say "without those gaps in between", so what will there be between the slices? If you plan to print, there must be a link between each iteration.

Comment: It looks like he wants to slice the object instead of duplicating each piece. Even if it ends up with the same result

Comment: Array modifier copies the whole object, I just have a plane circle, without any filling. 
If I can duplicate each piece that would be fine as well - I just need a DEFINED dimension that is repeating itself to create these layers.

Comment: I dont see why an array modifier wouldn't work then. You can set it to a constant offset and define that exact value on the XYZ coordinates.